# How to delete table having name ` in it

Tags: mysql

I have created and table named ***mytable`***.
tilled added by mistake at the end of table name. I am unable to select/update/insert/delete data from the table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly my question is different from you associated.

Comment: Did you try DROP

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with statement
DROP TABLE table_name

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it